# Connect spring boot project to database in sql management studio?

Tags: java, sql, database, spring-boot

I've been stuck with this task for a few hours, a few days ago I formatted my pc and I had to install everything again, IDE, database manager, jdk...etc.

The fact is that I've downloaded everything I need and I created a new project with spring initializer, and after hours of attempts I can't start it because it doesn't establish a connection to the database. I'm using sql management studio.

I leave here the pom.xml and aplciation properties,(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApC8I.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7KjK.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dex</groupId>
    <artifactId>testRestFul</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testRestFul</name>
    <description>Pruebas con apiRestFul</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I want to be able to connect my application with spring boot to a local db, if possible with sql management studio[The error that the console gives me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmsXf.png)

Comment: you are trying to us a MySQL Jdbc driver to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database. That isn't going to work. You need the SQL Server JDBC driver.

Comment: Thank you, but could you specify what I have to remove or add please, I'm a little lost

Comment: I do assume you know what you are doing. You are using Microsoft SQL Server and try to connect to it with a MySQL JDBC driver (`mysql-connector-java` and `mysql-connector-j` in your dependencies). MySQL is **not** Microsoft SQL Server, you will need other drivers for it, the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Drivers.

Comment: Hello and welcome. As stated above you need a proper driver. Just start over using https://start.spring.io/ but instead of MySQL select MS SQL Server Driver.